# Ideas for full text search MongoDB & node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lucene, sphinx, elasticsearch

I am developing a search engine for my website and i want to add following features to it;

1. Full text search
2. Did you mean feature
3. Data store in MongoDB

I want to make a restful backend. I will be add data to mongodb manually and it will be indexed (which one i can prefer? Mongodb indexing or some other search indexing libraries like Lucene). I also want to use node.js. These are what i found from my researches. Any idea would be appreciated for the architecture

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check out [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i think sphinx's latest stable version has some problems with handling mongodb document id s, Have you ever used sphinx with mongoDB?

Comment: No, I haven't. It was just a really general suggestion as a possible component of your solution, in case you didn't know of it. Sounds like you know more about integrating it with mongoDB than I do.

Comment: i used it for mysql and, i tried to use it for  mongodb. i just made a  little bit research on it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using Node.js / MongoDB / Elasticsearch (based on Lucene). It's an excellent combination. The flow is stunning as well, since all 3 packages (can) deal with JSON as their native format, so no need for transforming DTO's etc.

Have a look: 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i also resulted those 3 pairs but do you use "did you mean" feature like google search? I also need it. I think there is no such a future in elastic search

Comment: yeah you're right, they're waiting for Lucene 4.0 to be released before implementing it: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/911

Comment: Thanks, i also conlused like that. I will wait for that release.

Comment: can you please post a simple tutorial or some guidance on how to add Elastic search to node.js + mongodb?

Comment: Im with @MarwanRoushdy, any sample docs to tie these 3 together

Comment: Perhaps in the future. For now talk with ES over http/rest. Just using the HTTP-stuff in Node or use https://github.com/phillro/node-elasticsearch-client for a decent library. My way, is to do searchqueries in ES, and retrieve docids. These docids are then used to do a multikey fetch in mongoDB. This allows ES to stay lean (no need to store anything except the ids you need to do a fetch in Mongo), lesser problems with keeping datastores (mongodb and ES) in sync, etc. hth a bit

Answer (score 2):

I personally use Sphinx and MongoDb, it is a great pair and I have no problems with it.

I back MongoDB onto a MySQL instance which Sphinx just quickly indexes. Since you should never need to actively index _id, since I have no idea who is gonna know the _id of one of your objects to search for, you can just stash it in MySQL as a string field and it will work just fine.

When I pull the results back out of Sphinx all I do is convert to (in PHP) a new `MongoId`, or in your case a `ObjectId` and then simply query on this object id for the rest of the data. It couldn't be simpler, no problems, no hassle, no nothing. And I can spin off the load of reindexing delta indexes off to my MySQL instance keeping my MongoDB instance dealing with what it needs to: serving up tasty data for the user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and i will give a try to sphinx with mongodb

Comment: @cubuzoa np, one piece of advise; if your using it with the MySQL connector (like me) make sure to ue the default auto incrementing `id` of MySQL as the key for Sphinx to Delta Index on. I would recommend delta indexes over realtime indexes atm as well.